# "net use" didn't work in Python 3 script

Tags: python, network-drive, net-use

I want to access some files in my network drive.
My network drive is called  "networkfile". If I just run this on the Window command line, it is working:  net use \networkfile\Programs.

However, It didn't work when I put it in the Python script (I'm using Python3). I tried:

a = os.system("net use O:\networkfile\Programs")

a = os.system("net use \networkfile\Programs")

a = os.system("net use \networkfile\Programs")

a = subprocess.run("net use O:\networkfile\Programs", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

None of those work. The error is:  "System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found."

Anyone has experienced this before? 
Please advice.

Thanks,

Comment: `print("net use \networkfile\Programs")` and see what it shows you...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if it were just escaping, the third tiral would have solved the problem would it not?

Comment: @Aaron um, no, **you** seem to have edited in the escaping backslashes, changing the question completely...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my bad... I just hit the auto format as code tool. I didn't know it auto inserted backslashes

Comment: if command in Windows starts with `\\n` then in Python you have to use `\\\\n`. See `print('\\\\n', '\\n')` Or use raw string with prefix `r` - `print(r'\\n')`

Comment: @Aaron it's alright, I see what you mean. OP needs to show exactly what they are using...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that seems to me like a bug in the editor... It was my understanding that it simply indented any highlighted text four spaces with no other changes. I had no intention of changing the text in that way

Comment: @Aaron i think it's just markdown.

Comment: The double flash works.  This works for me:   a = os.system("net use \\\networkfile\\Programs")  . Thank you for all your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your string `"net use O:\networkfile\Programs"` is being evaluated by the python interpreter as:

```
net use O:
etworkfile\Programs
```

because the `\n` is interpreted as a newline character. You can work around this in a couple different ways

1. use a raw string (see four paragraphs down [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)) to prevent backslashes being treated specially (in most cases).
2. escape the backslashes themselves so they evaluate to a literal backslash (make all `"\"` into `"\\"`)
3. use the `os.path` library to generate the string so the correct directory separator is used regardless of operating system.

Comment: The double flash works.  This works for me:   a = os.system("net use \\\networkfile\\Programs")  . Thank you for all your help. I appreciate it.